# How do I edit the HTML form elements when in CSS? Do I assign an id?

Tags: html, css

```
<form id="form"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
   Status Message: <input type="text" name="statusmessage"/><br/> 
</form>
```

So, do I assign an id="name" within the brackets? And then in CSS, do I call it with #form name?

Comment: what do you mean by 'edit the HTML form elements'?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of different ways you can access any element in CSS. Well maybe not hundreds, but a lot. Read up on [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). Have you tried anything yet? If so, post the CSS, that would be a lot more useful to help you so we can see what you're doing wrong and can explain it to you.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="id" class="class" />
```

css: (any of the following would style the element)

```
input [name=name]{} 
#id{} 
.class{}
```

or you could style all text input fields in the form with:

```
#form input[type=text]{}
```

Comment: The alternatives `#id` and `.class` work on all CSS-enabled browsers, whereas `input[name=name]` is not recognized by old versions of IE. Another difference is that the selectors have different specificiy, which may have an effect in complex situations. Generally, `#id` is the most suitable selector when you wish to style a specific element.

Comment: true about the attribute selector, it is only useful if you don't intend to cater for IE<=6. I tend to use classes more than ids, purely because asp.net changes ids by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CSS2 you can use `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />` and then write this CSS:

```
#name {
    :
}
```

It will select the element with ID *name*. Remember that using additional address info is unnecessary since the ID is uniquely sufficient to select any single element.